# activerecord sort query codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$orders = $this->order->with("customer")->with("address")->get_many_by(array("submitted" => 1));
$this->main = $this->load->view("partials/admin/list_orders", array("allorders" => $orders), true);
```

This is my query, there is a column in table orders named as time, which includes date and time, I want query designed in such a way that returned results are sorted desc on basis of column time, can any one please help me or tell my how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a table like

```
id     |     name      |    date                  |  logic_erased
1           juan           2016-06-29 14:20:03          0
2           alfred         2016-06-29 14:19:58          0
```

and you want to sort date desc

```
$this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');

return $this->db->get_where('table', array('logic_erased' => 0))->result()
```

Comment: But my schema has foreign keys and it gets data from more than one table.

Comment: It dos't matter. you only have more options like `$this->db->select('tu.id, tu.name, td,id, td.option, tt.id, tt.value')->from('table_1 tu')->join('table_2 td', 'tu.table_2_fk = td.id')->join('table_3 tt', 'td.table_3_fk = tt.id')->where('tu.logic_erased', 0)->order_by('tt.date', 'desc');`

Comment: Okay, your approach is rewriting the whole query, is there any way to fulfill my requirement according my mentioned query in question?